# Is there an advantage in using 8-bit mode in 16x2 LCD displays?

Tags: arduino, lcd

Since almost all 16x2 LCD displays support 4-bit mode, and as it seems to be pretty efficient, is there a reason why they have 8-bit modes? I am using a JHD162A display with my Arduino Mega. Since the Mega has a lot of pins unused, I was wondering if I should use the display in 8-bit mode, if that could improve something. I do realize that I might be able to save a bit on the time factor by writing all 8 pins at the same time and not having to wait for the latching, and I just want to know if there's something else.

Answer (score 2):

The time, as you say, is the only thing I've found.
But it's both the added time out to the LCD and from the micro.
If you've got a time sensitive application (interrupt latency, etc), sending the full byte frees up the micro.